# Change edX email content and templates

Tags: edx, openedx

For LMS, I'm using my custom template, stored in directory:

/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes/my-theme/

Can you help me where are files I need to change, to change the look (and content) of emails sent by Open edX platform?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can find most of default email templates in

```
/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/templates/emails/
```

[image]

If you can not see the changes immediately, you may need to clear compiled folder

`/tmp/mako_lms/<some_hash>/emails/` directory.

For course bulk emails, you can change the email template in Django admin,
http://exmple.com/admin/bulk_email/courseemailtemplate/